# Position Material-UI Drawer component under Appbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a single-page application (Material-UI based) with an `AppBar` (+ `ToolBar`) and a `Drawer`. At the moment, the `Drawer` overlaps the `AppBar` and under no circumstances can I get the `Drawer` to move down, so it is basically positioned right under the `AppBar`.

I tried adding some padding, but this does not do anything. I'm using `makeStyles` for styling of most of the components, and I am wondering if it is even possible to position the `Drawer` below the `AppBar`.

Is there any way to position the drawer below the `AppBar`?

I have a lot of code, but the `makeStyle` function is simple:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  toolbar: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  drawer: {
    paddingTop: 30
  },
}));
```

and the main component (that includes the `Drawer`:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="absolute" >
          <Toolbar>  
            <Typography component="h1" variant="h6" noWrap className={classes.title}>
              x
            </Typography>
            <Switch checked={isDarkTheme} onChange={handleThemeSwitch}/>
            <WbIncandescentIcon />
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
        <ServiceDrawer className={classes.drawer} 
        onOperationSelected={onOperationSelect} serviceList={services} onDrawerOpen={onDrawerOpen} onDrawerClose={onDrawerClose}> 
        </ServiceDrawer>
        <main className={classes.content}>
            <div className={classes.toolbar} />
            {selectedOperation && <Operation operation={selectedOperation}/>}
        </main>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using v4 or v5?

Comment: @NearHuscarl v4

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variant of the `Drawer` to `permanent` so that it does not create an overlay over the current page, and put it inside the current app layout. Because the `Drawer` position is fixed, you also have to set the `AppBar` to `fixed` so they're on the same stacking context, and the z-index will be applied correctly, to put it in code:

```
<Drawer variant="permanent"
```

```
<AppBar position="fixed"
```

And finally the `zIndex` itself

```
appBar: {
  zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1
},
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

### Reference

- https://v4.mui.com/components/drawers/#clipped-under-the-app-bar

Comment: The top list item is behind the app bar